# rotating image on timer without blending the image

Tags: c#, image, timer, bitmap, rotation

i'm trying to make an animation of a wheel spinning using timer in c# (wheel image on pictureBox).

Method of rotating image:

```
public static Image RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
    {
        //create an empty Bitmap image
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

        //turn the Bitmap into a Graphics object
        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        //now we set the rotation point to the center of our image
        gfx.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2);

        //now rotate the image
        gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);

        gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2);

        //set the InterpolationMode to HighQualityBicubic so to ensure a high
        //quality image once it is transformed to the specified size
        gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        //now draw our new image onto the graphics object
        gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));

        //dispose of our Graphics object
        gfx.Dispose();

        //return the image
        return bmp;
    }
```

// code for timer tick

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float anglePerTick = 0;
        anglePerTick = anglePerSec / 1000 * timer1.Interval;
        pictureBox1.Image = RotateImage(pictureBox1.Image, anglePerTick);
    }
```

the image of the wheel keep spinning and the color is blending and then the image just fade out.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `anglePerSec` value, and what is `timer1.Interval` value? Did you try to increase Interval?

Answer (score 1):

When an image is rotated 90 degrees or any angle that's an exact multiple of 90, all pixel are preserved and they just move to their new location. But when you rotate at any other angle, resampling or approximating takes place, and no single pixel moves to a new pixel location, because pixel locations are integers but rotations at such angles produce non-integer locations. This means the new color of each pixel will come from blending between 4 and 6 pixels from the pre-rotated image. This blending will cause the fading you see. As a result, repeated rotations will introduce more and more distortion until the image is significantly altered or even completely destroyed.

The solution is to take a copy of the original image, then restore that original copy every time and rotate at the new angle. This way you will always get a single rotation done, and you won't accumulate distortions.